# Max Run Up function in pinescript

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have code that uses the strategy.opentrades.max_runup() function but my problem is that it only updated on bar close even when using calculate on every tick. I was wondering if anyone knew how to fix that or an alternative that calculates on every tick

I tried using strategy.opentrades.max_runup() to calculate the max run up which works but I wanted it to work on every tick but it only works on every bar close so the results aren’t as good

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.